# Find words inside object value key that are stored in an array

Tags: javascript, object

I receive an object which has many keys, two of them are "title" and "body", I also have an array that contains some keywords. I need to match those array keywords within the object.body to highlight them somehow, one option could be wrapping those matched words in a `<pre class="highlight"> Matched word inside Object.body </pre>` tag.

I would rather to achieve this using raw JavaScript.

I've tried:

```
function (data) {

        // parseKeys() returns an array with the words to find inside object.body
        var key_words = this.parseKeys();
 
// data is the object within I have to find inside key:body the array strings
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          if (data[i].body.includes(key)){
            console.log("****");
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: This is the forum where you put your doubts and errors in your tries. You should be posting your code. No one will write a code for you, after all, you have to try!

Comment: What have you tried so far? can you show us some code ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const keywords = ["doing", "only", "twice"];

const testObj = {
  title: "Whatever1",
  body: "Doing this only once or twice"
}

const checkBodyText = (obj) => {
  const bodyWords = obj.body.split(' ').map(el => el.toLowerCase());
  const matchingWords = bodyWords.filter(el => keywords.includes(el));
  const matchedWordsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('highlight')[0];
  matchedWordsContainer.innerText = matchingWords.join(' ');
}

checkBodyText(testObj);
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<pre class="highlight"></pre>
```

You can create a variable where you can keep your keywords.
I just created a dummy object and compared every word from "`object.body`" with any of the keywords from the list, the ones that are a match are just simply displayed. Ofc there will be some other edge scenarios to this approach, such as punctuation in the body sentence.